# C# Serialize with JSON

Tags: c#, json

I have the following class:

```
public class Employee 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age{ get; set; }

    public Employee(string name, int age)
     {
         Name = name;
         Age = age;
     }

     public override string ToString()
     {
         return string.Format("{0},{1}", Name, Age);
     } 
}
```

Now In another class I want to write a .json file to serialize the class Employee

```
public class WriteFile
{
   public void WriteInFile(List<Employee> list)
   {
        string filePath="File.json";

        var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create();

         using (var w = new StreamWriter(filePath)
         {

            using (JsonTextWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(w))
            {
                 foreach (Employee item in list)
                 {

                    string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item, Formatting.Indented);
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, s);

                  }
             }

            w.Close();
         }
    }
}
```

In Program class

```
class Program
{

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {

      List<Employee> listOfEmployees = new List<Employee>();
      listOfEmployees.Add(new Employee("Susan", 34 ));
      listOfEmployees.Add(new Employee("Jack", 50));
      listOfEmployees.Add(new Employee("Sally", 25));


      WriteFile write = new WriteFile();
      write.WriteInFile(listOfEmployees);

    }
}
```

The output is:

```
"{\r\n  \"Name\": \"Susan\",\r\n  \"Age\": 34\r\n}""{\r\n  \"Name\": \"Jack\",\r\n  \"Age\": 50\r\n}""{\r\n  \"Name\": \"Sally\",\r\n  \"Age\": 25\r\n}"
```

It seems like the formatting is not working properly. I want to have every Name and Age on a new line like:

```
"Name": "Susan", "Age": 34
```

and so on. Is this possible?

Comment: 1) Why are you converting to Json if you don't need that. 2) Why single object at a time instead of array? You can use stringBuilder or string to convert to format what you require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible.
Instead of using **JsonSerializer** again to write to the fie, append the content of serialized string to the text file.

```
string output = "";
foreach (Employee item in list)
{

    string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item, Formatting.Indented);
    output+= s+Environment.NewLine;
}
```

And finally write the output string to the file **without using JsonSerializer** again.

```
File.WriteAllText("output.json", output);
```

And then you will get the output file as,

```
{"Name":"Susan","Age":34}
{"Name":"Jack","Age":50} 
{"Name":"Sally","Age":25}
```

Answer (score 3):

JSON supports only one top level object or array (see the link to the JSON grammar below). To serialize a collection, serialize the collection itself. This will create a valid JSON array containing the elements.

```
public async Task WriteInFileAsync(IEnumerable<Employee> employees)
{
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employees, Formatting.Indented);
    await File.WriteAllTextAsync("employees.json", json);
}
```

[JSON grammar from json.org](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)